# Python searching in xml

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I would like to write a parser for an xml which can write out the data name and values(apple,10,...) into a txt.
This is the format of the file:

```
<b>Data1                    </b>: apple
<b>Data2                    </b>: 10
<b>Data3                    </b>: 01
<b>Data4                    </b>: 1001
```

This is just a small part of the file.
My idea is to write a for cycle which will go through the file lines by lines and check if it has this format. If it is true, than save the data name and the value.
How can i searching for these lines and save the data name and value?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is not clear what the problem is. Please don't just ask for solutions. What have you tried so far?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this code for getting all data from this xml

```
import re
file_content ="""<b>Data1                    </b>: apple
<b>Data2                    </b>: 10
<b>Data3                    </b>: 01
<b>Data4                    </b>: 1001"""
importent_lines = re.findall("\<b\>Data\d+\ *\<\/b\>\: \d+" , a)
data_list = [re.findall("\d+", line)[-1] for line in importent_lines]
```

you can remove the `importent_line` if all lines are in the same format and all line are importent and replace it with `file.readlines()`.

Comment: I have edited a little bit my question sorry. And as i know this:
 re.findall("\<b\>Data\d+\ *\<\/b\>\: \d+" , a)
will give back just the values which are digits, but i have words too.

Comment: So, you need to change those line to 'importent_lines = re.findall("\<b\>Data\d+\ *\<\/b\>\: \w+" , file_content)
data_list = [re.findall("\w+", line)[-1] for line in importent_lines]'